# Swift unable to get to the destination class whenever I select a row in the tableView row

Tags: swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

Simple situation. I am getting a crash whenever I select a row in View1.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NextScreen", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextScreenViewController") as! NextScreenViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
  }
```

I do have a NextScreen.xib that is a owner of this class NextScreenViewController
Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a crash error message or a line that is highlighted in red?

Comment: You need to make sure your storyboard has a NextScreenViewController registered with the identifier NextScreen.

Comment: I see a message with a crash in AppDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and your description don't match. Your code requires that you have a Storyboard file named "NextScreen", which contains a view controller with the identifier "NextScreenViewController", that is a subclass of UIViewController of type `NextScreenViewController`.

Your description says you have a NextScreen.xib that "is a owner of this class NextScreenViewController". Your code isn't trying to load a view controller from an XIB. It is trying to load it from a storyboard. Which is it?

XIB files and Storyboards are two different ways to include views in your project. If you save your view controller's views in an XIB, you need to load them from an XIB. If you save them in a storyboard, you need to load them fom a storyboard. **If you save your view controller's views in an XIB file and then try to load them from a storyboard, your app will crash.**

The crash log you added to your question makes it clear that the storyboard you are trying to load doesn't exist, and that is why you are crashing. It says "Could not find a storyboard named 'PlacesPlusScreen'." That is proof positive.

Do you have a Storyboard file in your project named "NextScreen", or an XIB file? What line is crashing? What is the exact error message?

Try changing your function like this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NextScreen", bundle: nil)
    guard let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextScreenViewController") as? NextScreenViewController else {
        print("Can't load storyboard with ID 'NextScreenViewController'")
        return
    }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
  }
```

Note that your line

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NextScreen", bundle: nil)
```

Will crash your program and throw an exception with the description "Could not find a storyboard named 'NextScreen' in bundle..." if it can't load your storyboard file.

So you, again, need to look at the exact crash message in the console, and report it here if you want our help debugging the problem.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. You are trying to load your view controller's views from a Storyboard when you instead saved them to a XIB file.

Answer (score 0):

This the place where it crashes

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PlacesPlusScreen", bundle: nil)
    guard let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlacesPlusScreenController") as? PlacesPlusScreenController else {
            print("Can't load storyboard with ID 'PlacesPlusScreenController'")
            return
        }
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)

  }
```

Here is are class

```
class PlacesPlusScreenController: UIViewController
```

Here is the hierarchy where the xib file and the PlacesPlusScreen are there.

[image]
Here is the crash report

```
07-22 20:49:44.080494-0700 Example[14820:6956631] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'PlacesPlusScreen' in bundle NSBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/87BBA05A-9FF9-4851-A4FB-05DF7938E232/Example.app> (loaded)'
*** Ffirst throw call stack:
(0x184c9e754 0x1997657a8 0x187810ffc 0x102fbca0c 0x102fbc730 0x102fbcaec 0x18789f1d0 0x18789ed78 0x18789f538 0x187b69c98 0x18769c6c4 0x18768b03c 0x1876bef10 0x184c175e0 0x184c11704 0x184c11cb0 0x184c11360 0x19c24f734 0x18768c584 0x187691df4 0x102fc9478 0x1848cdcf8)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'PlacesPlusScreen' in bundle NSBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/87BBA05A-9FF9-4851-A4FB-05DF7938E232/JacquardSDK_Example.app> (loaded)'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to only do this!

```
 let vc = PlacesPlusScreenController()
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: That will create an instance of `PlacesPlusScreenController`, but it won't have any of its views loaded from your nib (XIB) file. Invoking a view controller that way is usually wrong. You should use `init(nibName:bundle:)` to create a view controller from a nib (XIB) file. (They used to be called nib files, but were renamed to XIB. Many of the functions still refer to them as nibfiles, and Mac/iOS old-timers still call them that.)